# Can't open port 3306 for remote connection

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, remote-connection

I understand this question has been asked but they all say the same thing which I have tried and failed.

Basically using this site: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
I can see my 3306 port is closed and trying to get a client to connect remotely is not working. I have changed the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file to both commented out `bind-address` and also change it to `0.0.0.0` but neither worked.

I have tried `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

My iptables all show ACCEPT

`-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

`ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306`

Does anyone have any other idea as to why this port is still blocked?

Thanks

Additional information [EDIT]

When I try to use: `mysqli_connect('XX.XX.XX.XXX', "DBUSer", "DBPassword", "DBName", 3306);` it gives my the error `PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX (60)`

I also typed into my server:
`ufw status;
Status: inactive`

Comment: Is there a hardware firewall?

Comment: Is the server on the internet, or is it on a private network?

Comment: Is there a software firewall? Fiddling around with the MySQL configuration is starting at the wrong end. The first question is, what error do your clients get? 'Connection refused' or 'connect timeout'?

Comment: It is a custom built application that just says 'unable to connect to mysql database'. But that could mean anything. I get a php error when using mysqli_connect: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX (60) if that helps. command `mysqli_connect('XX.XX.XX.XXX', "DBUSer", "DBPassword", "DBName", 3306);`

Comment: It is a server on the internet for a website application we have developed.

Comment: I also typed: `ufw status; Status: inactive` so does that mean my firewall is inactive?

Comment: Did you restart mysql server service after change /etc/mysql/my.cnf? This seems obvious but...the server is running/

Comment: Yeah I restarted it. Still nothing.

Comment: Try `telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 3306` and tell us the result.

Comment: NB `(60)` is an `errno` value in your local systenm. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

Turns out the team that set up the server needed to make a change on their end. They didn't say specifically but it opened the port up. (I imagine it was a firewall setting)

I also had to grant privileges to all host with:

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to DBUsername@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'DBPassword';`

I had always seen the DBUsername@'xx.xx.xx.xxx' and didn't know I had to '%' it to work for all IPs.

Thanks

Comment: What firewall setting did your team change? I'm still not able to open that port. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and i try add a new rule in outbound rule (in firewall advanced setting) for port 3306. Or you can configure the Mysql setting, while you setting, tick the box to allow remote from another machine.